# How could I replace the following JS code using the map function?

Tags: javascript

So, I've been working on this algorithm and in this specific part, I'm using for...of, how could this be replaced in a functional way?

```
const friendsOfFriendsIdsArr = [];
  for (const user of graph) {
    if (userFriends.includes(user.id)) {
      friendsOfFriendsIdsArr.push(...user.friends);
    }
  }
```

Comment: A map function replaces every element of the array with another value. You're looking for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten nested array of object using es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435515/how-to-flatten-nested-array-of-object-using-es6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map a javascript array to another javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077318/how-to-map-a-javascript-array-to-another-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the below,

```
const friendsOfFriendsIdsArr = [];
  for (const user of graph) {
    if (userFriends.includes(user.id)) {
      friendsOfFriendsIdsArr.push(...user.friends);
    }
  }
```

becomes,

```
graph.reduce(user =>{
  if (userFriends.includes(user.id)) acc.push(user.friends)

  return acc
}, [])
```